# Ruby if inside map to pass in hash

Tags: ruby

I've got a method where I'm iterate through the hash by `.map` to create another hash as the results.

```
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    {
      key: issue.key,
      desired_time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_14777.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly'),
      time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_10031.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly'),
      name: issue.name
    }
  end
end
```

How to put if block inside of this hash to decide to put there `desired_time_to_resolution:` or `time_to_resolution`?

I mean if block like this:

```
if issue.customfield_14777.nil?
  desired_time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_14777.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly')
else
  time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_10031.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly')
end
```

Comment: `assigned_tasks` can only be a method, as it was not passed to the method as an argument. Does it return an array of instances of a class? Please clarify. Note you have no Rails tag and Ruby has no core method `present`.

Comment: It's pure ruby class and this if block is a just an example like I wrote. `assigned_tasks` is a private method, I don't see any reason to show what is inside of this method. I think it doesn't matter in that case but yes, array of instances of a class with `@attrs = { 'key' => 'value', ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it *inside* the hash, but you can use `Hash#merge` to update the hash.

```rb
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    {
      key: issue.key,
      name: issue.name
    }.merge(
      if issue.customfield_14777.present?
        {desired_time_to_resolution: ...}
      else
        {time_to_resolution: ...}
      end
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your question is similar to the following one.

```
class C
  attr_reader :name, :is_k1, :k1, :k2, :v
  def initialize(name, is_k1, k1, k2, v)
    @name, @is_k1, @k1, @k2, @v = name, is_k1, k1, k2, v
  end
end
```

```
c1 = C.new("Bob", true, :a, :b, 1)
  #=> #<C:0x0000583742602eb8 @name="Bob", @is_k1=true, @k1=:a,
  #     @k2=:b, @v=1> 
c2 = C.new("Lois", false, :c, :d, 2)
  #=> #<C:0x0000583742612ac0 @name="Lois", @is_k1=false, @k1=:c,
  #     @k2=:d, @v=2>
```

We want to map each instance `i` (`c1` or `c2`) into the hash:

```
{ name: i.name, i.k1: i.v }
```

if `i.is_k1 #=> true` and into the hash

```
{ name: i.name, i.k2: i.v }
```

if `i.is_k1 #=> false`. We could simply write:

```
[c1, c2].map { |i| { name: i.name, (i.is_k1 ? i.k1 : i.k2)=>i.v } }
  #=> [{:name=>"Bob", :a=>1}, {:name=>"Lois", :d=>2}]
```

Comment: Muscle-guy: please let me know if I've misinterpreted the question. If I have I will change or delete my answer.